# Rsync the lastest two files of a pattern from remote

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I want to rsync the latest two files of a certain pattern between two servers in different environments:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 transfer transfer          4096 28. Nov 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 transfer transfer          4096 28. Nov 13:05 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer transfer   11151643678 28. Nov 12:46 test_28-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer transfer         29789 28. Nov 13:04 test_28-11-2023.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer transfer   10770251760 28. Nov 13:00 test_anonym_19-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer transfer         48408 28. Nov 13:02 test_anonym_19-11-2023.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer transfer    9329096219 28. Nov 13:03 test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer transfer         48407 28. Nov 13:03 test_anonym_21-11-2023.log
```

Since only want to transfer the latest `*.gz` and `*.log` of the pattern `\.\/test_anonym_.*\.*` I can do something like this to identify them:

```
user@host:~/folder$ find . -type f -regex '\.\/test_anonym_.*\.*' | sort -r | head -n 2
./test_anonym_21-11-2023.log
./test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz
```

Or directly identify them on the remote with `ssh` like this (which works fine):

```bash
user@host:~/folder$ ssh -qx user@host "ls -t /home/user/folder | sort -r | head -n 2"
test_anonym_21-11-2023.log
test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz
```

The following `rsync` command transfers too much because I am only using a pattern of one file type and not identifying the latest files of both types:

```
user@host:~/folder$ rsync -av --stats --include='test_anonym_*.gz' --exclude='test_*.*' user@host:/home/user/folder/ /home/user/folder/

test_anonym_19-11-2023.dmp.gz
test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz
```

I tried using `ssh` and `rsync` together after sifting through many man pages and posts like this, but it fails in the `ssh` step which is never completed:

```
ssh user@host "ls -t /home/user/folder/ | sort -r | head -n 2" | rsync -0 --stats --files-from=- -av user@host:/home/user/folder/ /home/user/folder/
```

I tried using `rsync` with `--files-from=` option but have also failed because I am unsure of the syntax here in my two examples:

```
rsync -a --stats --files-from=<(ssh user@host 'find . -type f -regex '\./test_anonym_.*\.*' | sort -r | head -n 2') --exclude='test_*.*' user@host:/home/user/folder/ /home/folder/folder/

rsync -a --stats --files-from=<(find . -type f -regex '\.\/test_anonym_.*\.*' | sort -r | head -n 2) --exclude='test_*.*' user@host:/home/user/folder/ /home/folder/folder/
```

I'm not sure how to put it all together (or if it's even possible) to find and sync the desired files; I'm really stuck now. How can I make this work? My workstation uses `zsh`, my remotes all use `bash`.

To reiterate my expectations here: I want to `rsync` (with/without `ssh`) two files of a different type from a remote, i.E. `test_anonym_21-11-2023.log` and `test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz` witch match my pattern and are the latest two files of their type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU tools you can use `find` to identify the two most recently modified files and transfer just those. The process is complicated a little by the need to pull the files from a remote host, but that just means `ssh` gets more involved.

If we can assume that the two most recently modified files are the pair of files to be transferred, and that we have tools with GNU extensions (or similar):

```
ssh -qn remoteHost "find folder -name 'test_anonym_*' -printf '%T@ %p\0'" |
    sort -z -k1,1rn |
    head -z -n2 |
    cut -z -d' ' -f2- |
    rsync --dry-run -av --files-from - --from0 remoteHost: "$HOME/folder"
```

If you do not have GNU tools you have to be careful of unexpected file names but this pipeline will work provided you have control of the file names placed in `folder`:

```
ssh -qn remoteHost ls -t folder |
    head -n2 |
    rsync --dry-run -av --files-from - --from0 remoteHost:folder/ "$HOME/folder"
```

In both cases remove `--dry-run` when you're happy the code is doing what you expect.

If you can only guarantee (say) the `dmp.gz` file and you want to pull the associated `log` file, that gets more complex. But that doesn't seem to have been required by your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a test under Debian and update the question need be.

Answer (score 0):

If the login shell of the target user on `remoteHost` is zsh, that should just be matter of:

```
rsync --old-args 'remoteHost:folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])' ~/folder/
```

With `--old-args`, needed in newer versions of `rsync` where that behaviour is no longer the default, the `folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])` is passed as-is in the remote shell command line that invokes `rsync --server`, and the shell will expand that glob which here matches on the two most recent files in `folder` whose name starts with `test_anonym` and ends in either `.gz` or `.log`.

You can find the difference in behaviour when using `--old-args` and not and when using `--protect-args` by running `rsync` under `strace -e execve`:

```
$ strace -fe execve rsync --old-args 'remoteHost:folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])' ~/folder/
[...]
[pid  8483] execve("/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "remoteHost", "rsync", "--server", "--sender", "-e.LsfxCIvu", ".", "folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om"...], 0x7ffceb4e2cf0 /* 52 vars */) = 0
[...]
```

Arg passed unmodified.

```
$ strace -fe execve rsync 'remoteHost:folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])' ~/folder/
[...]
[pid  8489] execve("/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "remoteHost", "rsync", "--server", "--sender", "-e.LsfxCIvu", ".", "folder/test_anonym*.\\(log\\|gz\\)\\"...], 0x7ffc5bced518 /* 52 vars */) = 0
[...]
```

Some characters were escaped with `\`, whether that's a valid thing to do for the remote shell or not.

```
$ strace -fe execve rsync --protect-args  'remoteHost:folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])' ~/folder/
[...]
[pid  8507] execve("/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "remoteHost", "rsync", "--server", "--sender", "-se.LsfxCIvu"], 0x7ffc404a9900 /* 52 vars */) = 0
[...]
```

The arg is not passed in the shell command line but inband in the newer rsync protocol. In general, that's the safest, but that wouldn't allow us to use advanced globbing operators of your shell.

If zsh is installed on the remote host, but the login shell of the user is bash instead, you can convince bash there to get zsh to run the rsync server command using a trick like:

```
rsync --rsync-path='zsh -c "${BASH_EXECUTION_STRING#*\#\ }" # rsync' \
  --old-args 'remoteHost:folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])' ~/folder/
```

Where bash on the remote host will be asked to evaluate:

```
zsh -c "${BASH_EXECUTION_STRING#*\#\ }" # rsync --server --sender -e.LsfxCIvu . folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])
```

Where the whole `rsync --server...` command is just treated as a comment.

`$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` is automatically set by bash to the inline script being executed, and we strip everthing from it up to the first occurrence of `#` , so `zsh` will get to interpret:

```
rsync --server --sender -e.LsfxCIvu . folder/test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])
```

If you don't need the *syncing* capability of `rsync` but just need to transfer those files, it may be easier just to do:

```
ssh remoteHost zsh << 'EOF' | (cd ~/folder && tar zxpvf -)
  cd folder &&
    tar zcf - test_anonym*.(log|gz)(.om[1,2])
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, I'll give it a test under Debian and comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**My original question:**

> *"I want to rsync the latest two files of a certain pattern between two servers in different environments."*

My (transfer) host server with the latest files:

```bash
drwxrwxr-x 2 transfer 4,0K 26. Mär 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 transfer 4,0K 20. Mär 11:01 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer    0 26. Mär 13:30 test_26-03-2024.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer    0 26. Mär 13:30 test_26-03-2024.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer    0 28. Nov 12:46 test_28-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer   21 28. Nov 13:04 test_28-11-2023.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer   0 26. Mär 13:30 test_anonym_17-03-2024.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer    0 26. Mär 13:30 test_anonym_17-03-2024.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer    0 28. Nov 13:00 test_anonym_19-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer    5 29. Jan 13:35 test_anonym_19-11-2023.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer    0 28. Nov 13:03 test_anonym_21-11-2023.dmp.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 transfer  497 29. Jan 13:36 test_anonym_21-11-2023.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer    0 29. Jan 13:38 test_anonym_29-01-2024.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 transfer  201 29. Jan 13:37 test_anonym_29-01-2024.log
user@transfer:~/folder$
```

**The solution to my issue:**

I identified the two latest files of the naming pattern `test_anonym_*.*` and the file types `.log` and `.dmp.gz` from my (devops) other server and save the output as a text file:

```bash
user@devops:~$ ssh -qx user@transfer 'ls -tr /home/user/folder | sort -k 8,8n -k 6,6M | grep test_anonym_* | head -n 2' > output.txt
...
user@devops:~$ nl output.txt 
     1  test_anonym_17-03-2024.dmp.gz
     2  test_anonym_17-03-2024.log
```

I can now `rsync` the files contained in my text file to my other server:

```bash
user@devops:~$ rsync -arv --stats --include-from=output.txt --exclude=* user@transfer:folder/ ./folder/
user@transfer's password: 
receiving incremental file list
./
test_anonym_17-03-2024.dmp.gz
test_anonym_17-03-2024.log
...
sent 139 bytes  received 211 bytes  100,00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0,00
```

The correct files were transferred and my main issue was resolved:

```bash
user@devops:~$ ls -la folder/
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 26. Mär 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 user user 4096 26. Mär 14:55 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 26. Mär 13:30 test_anonym_17-03-2024.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 26. Mär 13:30 test_anonym_17-03-2024.log
```

**Nice to have:**
The solution would now be to combine the `ssh` and `rsync` command to one single command via piping or saving the `ls`, `sort`, `grep` and `head` to *tmp* from the `--include-from=` but no one seems to be able to offer support for this.

Comment: "_The solution would now be to combine the ssh and rsync command to one single command via piping_" - what, like in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/764911/100397) or [Stéphane's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/764913/100397)?